# What is the use of @EnableWebSecurity in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, annotations

As per the [Spring documantation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html):

> Add this annotation to an `@Configuration` class to have the Spring
> Security configuration defined in any `WebSecurityConfigurer` or more
> likely by extending the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` base class and
> overriding individual methods:

Or As this `@EnableWebSecurity` depicts, is used to enable SpringSecurity in our project.

But my question is that even if I don't annotate any of my class with `@EnableWebSecurity` still the application prompting for username and password.(default behaviour)

So I am receiving the same behaviour with `@EnableWebSecurity` and without `@EnableWebSecurity`.

Can someone please explain what exactly is this annotation for?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `@EnableWebSecurity` is a marker annotation. It allows Spring to find (it's a `@Configuration` and, therefore, `@Component`) and automatically apply the class to the global `WebSecurity`.

> If I don't annotate any of my class with `@EnableWebSecurity` still the application prompting for username and password.

Yes, it is the default behavior. If you looked at your classpath, you could find other classes marked with that annotation (depends on your dependencies):

- `SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration`;
- `FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration`;
- `WebMvcSecurityConfiguration`.

Consider them carefully, turn the needed configuration off, or override its behavior.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "apply it to the global `WebSecurity`"?

Comment: Hi @andrewtobilko I am using Spring Security 3.0.5 and it does not have EnableWebSecurity annotation. Can you please suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 38):

The [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) explains well about it. If you search with `@EnableWebSecurity`:

> To switch off the default web application security configuration completely you can add a bean with `@EnableWebSecurity` (this does not disable the authentication manager configuration or Actuator’s security). To customize it you normally use external properties and beans of type `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (e.g. to add form-based login).
>
> ...
>
> If you add `@EnableWebSecurity` and also disable Actuator security, you will get the default form-based login for the entire application unless you add a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.
>
> ...
>
> If you define a `@Configuration` with `@EnableWebSecurity` anywhere in your application it will switch off the default webapp security settings in Spring Boot (but leave the Actuator’s security enabled). To tweak the defaults try setting properties in `security.*` (see `SecurityProperties` for details of available settings) and SECURITY section of Common application properties.

Apparently, it's to switch off the default web application security configuration and add your own.

Comment: No more found in recent Spring Boot Doc. Rather, it says "To switch off the default web application security configuration completely or to combine multiple Spring Security components such as OAuth2 Client and Resource Server, add a bean of type SecurityFilterChain (doing so does not disable the UserDetailsService configuration or Actuator’s security)."

Answer (score 14):

The answer depends on whether you are using Spring Boot or not.

If you are using Spring and Spring Security WITHOUT Spring Boot, The @EnableWebSecurity does just you described in your original question: it will automatically define and configure several beans, the filter chain, etc. to enable basic security for a web application.

If you are using Spring Boot, autoconfiguration classes (See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security) will autoconfigure security beans for you.  There is no need for @EnableWebSecurity.  In fact with Boot, there is generally no need for any of  Spring's @Enable* annotations.

...Unless you don't like the way Spring Boot's autoconfiguration classes setup security.  @EnableWebSecurity would cause Spring Security's setup to take precedent and cause Spring Boot autoconfiguration to back off.  (This is sometimes desirable when you are converting an existing Spring Security application to Spring Boot and want to minimize changes.)

Spring Boot's autoconfiguration default behavior and @EnableWebSecurity default behavior are pretty darn close.  This is why you observed no difference when you removed the annotation.

Comment: May be out of original context. @EnableJpaAuditing is needed explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

`@EnableWebSecurity` is used for spring security java configuration. Add this annotation with `@configuration` on top of your security java class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Override the `configure(WebSecurity web)` & `configure(HttpSecurity http)`. This is the replacement of xml based configurations like `<http>` and `<form login>`. This way you can limit requested urls coming from specific urls also enable form based log in.

Comment: Thanks , but this does not seem to answer the main question. If we don't add @EnableWebSecurity,  but merely create the security java class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter...  Will that still works?